# Powershell - Remove recycle bin items older than 1 year

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-api, powershell

Running version `Sitecore 9.3` - and the latest version of the `Powershell` package

The Powershell documentation has an example of `deleting an individual item`.

```
$database = Get-Database -Name "master"
$archiveName = "recyclebin"
$archive = Get-Archive -Database $database -Name $archiveName
Remove-ArchiveItem -Archive $archive -ItemId "{1BB32980-66B4-4ADA-9170-10A9D3336613}"
```

Is it possible to have the Remove-archive item iterate through the whole list of archived items, but only delete items older than 1 year?

*** Edit
I managed to put a solution together prior to both of the Sumits who posted, but their solutions are cleaner.

```
function GetRecycleBinItems {

$database = Get-Database -Name "master"
$archiveName = "recyclebin"
$archive = Get-Archive -Database $database -Name $archiveName
Get-ArchiveItem -Archive $archive
}

$limit = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-365)

$items = GetRecycleBinItems
foreach($item in $items) {
    if ($item.ArchiveDate -lt $limit) {
        Remove-ArchiveItem -Archive $archive -ItemId $item.ItemId
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your working solution as an answer instead of editing the question. You can also accept your own answer. Refer - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the official documentation given by Sitecore where you can find the examples to iterate through the archive items. Hope this document link will work for others to get multiple examples of PowerShell scripts. Here is the link.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/code-snippets

You will find lots of code snippets and the code you are looking for is under the **Restore Recycle bin items** section. That is used to restore the items. But in your case you want to delete those items then you can modify your code a little bit.

```
[datetime]$archivedDate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-365)  #Add the days

foreach($archive in Get-Archive -Name "recyclebin") {
    $entries = $archive.GetEntries(0, $archive.GetEntryCount())
    foreach($entry in $entries) {
        if($entry.ArchiveLocalDate -ge $archivedDate) { 
             $archive.RemoveEntries($entry.ArchivalId)
        } 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to put together a solution late yesterday afternoon but this is a much cleaner loop.

Comment: Technically the documentation is by me, not Sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete entries from recycle bin based on any date by passing the `days value` in the below script. As it sets to **-356** days to delete only items older than 1 year. You can change the day value according to your need to change the date value.

```
[datetime]$archivedDate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-365)
Write-Host "Delete items older then $($archivedDate.ToShortDateString())"

foreach($archive in Get-Archive -Name "recyclebin") {
    Write-Host " - Found $($archive.GetEntryCount()) entries"
    $entries = $archive.GetEntries(0, $archive.GetEntryCount())
    foreach($entry in $entries) {
        if($entry.ArchiveLocalDate -ge $archivedDate) { 
            Write-Host "Delete item: $($entry.OriginalLocation) {$($entry.ArchivalId)} on date $($entry.ArchiveLocalDate)"
            $archive.RemoveEntries($entry.ArchivalId)
        } else {
            Write-Host "Skipping $($entry.OriginalLocation) on date $($entry.ArchiveLocalDate)"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfect example. If my rep was higher I would vote both of the answers up for how well they were written